# Why are negative numbers greater than positive numbers?

Tags: c, sorting, memcmp

I made my bubble sort program generic. I went on testing it and it was working well until I placed a negative number in the array, and I was surprised that it was pushed to the end, making it bigger than positive numbers.

Obviously `memcmp` is the reason, so why does `memcmp()` regard negative numbers greater than positive numbers?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void bubblesortA(void *_Buf, size_t bufSize, size_t bytes);

int main(void)
{
    size_t n, bufsize = 5;
    int buf[5] = { 5, 1, 2, -1, 10 };
    bubblesortA(buf, 5, sizeof(int));

    for (n = 0; n < bufsize; n++)
    {
        printf("%d ", buf[n]);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    char str[] = "bzqacd";
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    bubblesortA(str, len, sizeof(char));

    for (n = 0; n < len; n++)
    {
        printf("%c ", str[n]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}

void bubblesortA(void *buf, size_t bufSize, size_t bytes)
{
    size_t x, y;
    char *ptr = (char*)buf;
    void *tmp = malloc(bytes);
    for (x = 0; x < bufSize; x++)
    {
        ptr = (char *)buf;
        for (y = 0; y < (bufSize - x - 1); y++)
        {
            if (memcmp(ptr, ptr + bytes, bytes) > 0)
            {
                memcpy(tmp, ptr, bytes);
                memcpy(ptr, ptr + bytes, bytes);
                memcpy(ptr + bytes, tmp, bytes);
            }
            ptr += bytes;
        }
    }
    free(tmp);
}
```

**Edit**:
So, How do I modify the program to make it compare correctly?

Comment: maybe because sign bit is 1 for -ve numbers?

Comment: Note: Nice `bubblesortA()`.  Try with 2 negative `int`s --> `1, 3, -3, -1`.  Now try this with `double`.  You may get a sort like `1.0, 3.0, -1.0, -3.0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering OP's appended edit

> How can i modify the program to make it compare correctly?

To compare two types as an anonymous bit pattern, `memcmp()` works fine.  To compare two values of some type, code needs a compare function for that type.  Following `qsort()`  style:

```
void bubblesortA2(void *_Buf,size_t bufSize,size_t bytes, 
    int (*compar)(const void *, const void *)))
{
   ....
        // if(memcmp(ptr,ptr+bytes,bytes) > 0)
        if((*compar)(ptr,ptr+bytes) > 0)
   ....
```

To compare `int`, pass in a compare `int` function.  Notice that `a`, `b` are the addresses to the objects.

```
int compar_int(const void *a, const void *b) {
  const int *ai = (const int *)a;
  const int *bi = (const int *)b;
  return (*ai > *bi) - (*ai < *bi);
}
```

To compare `char`, pass in a compare `char` function

```
int compar_int(const void *a, const void *b) {
  const char *ac = (const char *)a;
  const char *bc = (const char *)b;
  return (*ac > *bc) - (*ac < *bc);
}
```

Comment: nice,i tried it and it worked.but your solution means that i have to make a similar function to each datatype i want use,right?

Comment: @machine_1 Yes - a compare function per type.  Could modify `(*compar)` to take a 3rd parameter, some pointer maybe, that directs the compare function is some way.  Maybe potential approaches to solve this, yet keep `bubblesort()` generic.

Comment: @machine_1 Suggest reading about `qsort()`, `bsearch()` and especially [`qsort_r()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html)

Comment: @machine_1 Probably would have been better to accept [@alain](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33915401/2410359) fine answer and then have posted a new question with "How can i modify the program to make it compare correctly?"

Answer (score 7):

`memcmp` compares bytes, it does not know if the bytes represent `int`s, `double`s, strings, ...

So it can not do any better that treat the bytes as unsigned numbers. Because a negative integer is normally represented using two's-complement, the highest bit of a negative integer is set, making it bigger than any positive signed integer.

Comment: So,how can i fix the program to discover that negative numbers are less than positive numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Negative numbers have sign bit (the most significant bit) set to 1. Function `memcmp` compares bytes as unsigned values. So it considers the sign bit as a value bit. As result sometimes negative numbers are greater than positive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In the notation that numbers and negative numbers are counted, the first bit is used as signbit, a bit that indicates wether a number is negative or positive.

It becomes clear if we look at the binary representations of 2 numbers. Its worth noting that `memcmp` just compares 2 numbers as if they were both unsigned numbers of the lenght specified.

-27 in binary notation (8 bit notation, twos complement): `1110 0101`

+56 in binary notation : `0011 1000`

If you compare the two as if they were positive, you'll note that the -27 representation is actually bigger.